# input type time is not sending data in desired format in React MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, time, material-ui

i have textfield with type=time , it takes an input in "hh:mm AM/PM" but sending value in just "hh:mm" format

check here

[image: input and response]

how to send input in the same format that user typed in textfield ?

code for input field

```
 <TextField
              sx={{
                '& input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator': {
                  filter:
                    "invert(78%) sepia(66%) saturate(6558%) hue-rotate(84deg) brightness(27%) contrast(16%)",
                  paddingRight: "8px",
                },
              }}
              name="startTime"
              type="time"
              id="startTime"
              value={values.startTime}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
```

code for handling and sending time value

```
const initialValues = { startTime: "" };
  const { values, errors, touched, handleBlur, handleChange, 
         handleSubmit } =
        useFormik({
          enableReinitialize: true,
          initialValues,
          onSubmit: async (values, action) => {
            try {
                     let response = await axios.patch(
                    `${state.baseUrl}plan`,
                    {start_time: values.startTime},
               );
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @AjmalNoushad done , can i post code of api handling too ?

Comment: yes and also include the `handleChange` function

Comment: add the code and i'm using handleChange of formik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the native input `type="time"`. And it would always return the time in 24 hours format, even if the visible value is in 12 hours format.

That is if you choose `11:59 PM` in the input, the value you would get will be "23:59" which is the 24 hours format. This is a limitation of the native time input.

More details at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#time_value_format

So in this case you would need to manually convert the 24 hours format time string to 12 hours time string.

```
const convert24to12 = (time) => {
  // Extract hours and minutes from the time string
  const hours = parseInt(time.slice(0, 2));
  const minutes = time.slice(3, 5);

  // Determine AM or PM
  const amOrPm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

  // Convert hours to 12-hour format
  const twelveHourTime = `${(hours % 12) || 12}:${minutes} ${amOrPm}`;

  return twelveHourTime;
}

     <TextField
        //other props
        onChange={e => {
          const 12hourString = convert24to12(e.target.value);
          // Using setFieldValue from formik
          setFieldValue("startTime", 12hourString)
        }}
     />
```

A better solution would be to use a custom time picker from which you can output the time. I see you are using MUI, which already provides a nice time picker component here: https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/.